# Query To Select Row With Specific ID For Each Of Two Unique Fields & Count Position Of Third Field

Tags: php, mysql

My relevant table structure is like so (with `id` being primary key and having autoincrement):

```
id | pid | type | distance | pspeed
```

Each `pid` (player id) has a unique row for every `type` and `pspeed` combination. For example, there is no row with a specific `pid` value, a specific `type` value, and more than one `pspeed` value. Likewise for `pid` and `pspeed`, there is not more than one row with the same `type` value.

My goal is to, for every `type` (there are 26 total), group by pspeed (there are 7 different pspeed values) and sort by distance descending until a specific `pid` value is found and return that row with the "rank" or "position" of that row. Basically I want to do a `ORDER BY distance` for each `type` and `pspeed` until a specific `pid` value is reached.

Is this possible via pure queries? I know how to do this with several queries and loops in a PHP script but I would like to be able to minimize the code I have to write. Unfortunately, I'm quite positive it would require SQL knowledge that is beyond me.

If counting up until a specific `pid` value is not possible I can just bake that into my PHP script to determine the "rank".

---

Edit: here is how I'm currently doing this (using CodeIgniter):

```
$res = array();
$q1 = $this->db1->get_where('uq_players', array('authid' => $authid), 1);
if($q1->num_rows()){
    foreach($this->jtype as $type => $value){
        foreach($this->pspeed as $speed){
            $i = 0;
            $this->db1->order_by('distance', 'desc');
            $q2 = $this->db1->get_where('uq_jumps', array('type' => $type, 'pspeed' => $speed));
            foreach($q2->result() as $row){
                $i += 1;
                if($row->pid === $q1->row()->id){
                    $res[] = self::create_array($row, $type, $row->wpn, $i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And [some sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0255a).

Comment: can you give an example of the output you want and data you are working with? Maybe try [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for more clarity.

Comment: @Adunahay edited as per request.

Comment: I wouldn't mention it for just one post, but I notice that all of your question Use Title Case for their titles. The community [tends to prefer sentence casing here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles), as it is thought to be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first try geting a rowset of all different scores for a given player and all combinations of type and pspeed, then left join all other scores with the same type and pspeed but greater distance. If your player is ranked first for this combination you will get one row with nulls, otherwise you will get number of rows equal to number of players with greater distance, which incremented will give you the players rank.

```
SELECT t1.type, t1.pspeed, 1+SUM(t2.pid IS NOT NULL) as rank
FROM scores t1
LEFT JOIN scores t2 
  ON t1.type = t2.type AND t1.pspeed = t2.pspeed AND t1.distance < t2.distance
WHERE t1.pid = 1
GROUP BY t1.type, t1.pspeed
```

See [Sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8244d/2).

Comment: No idea how you can manage to write this so easily. To me, mastering RegEx seems like it was easier than learning basic SQL querying. :(